# ImageMagick Command Substitution in Windows Shell

Tags: windows, shell, imagemagick, dos

How should i convert the following imagemagick command to use in DOS? As far as i understand i can't convert it directly and have to use a for loop in a batch file, but had no success so far.

```
convert noisy.jpg -crop `convert noisy.jpg -virtual-pixel edge -blur 0x15 -fuzz 15% -trim -format '%wx%h%O' info:` +repage noisy_trimmed_2.jpg
```

Comment: perhaps use www.cygwin.com?

Comment: @FredrikPihl not an option in this case :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway i got it working like this, and @devnull s answer was helpful but i didn't use "usebackq delims=" . You also need to escape %'s by putting one more % before each.

```
FOR /F %%A IN ('convert xxx.jpg -virtual-pixel edge -blur 0x15 -fuzz 15%% -trim -format "%%wx%%h%%O" info:') DO convert xxx.jpg -crop %%A +repage yyy.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need the `for` command in order to capture the output of the command to be passed as a parameter.  It can be squeezed into one line by saying:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%info in (`convert noisy.jpg -virtual-pixel edge -blur 0x15 -fuzz 15% -trim -format '%wx%h%O' info:`) do convert noisy.jpg -crop %%info +repage noisy_trimmed_2.jpg
```

Comment: no, the error: %info was not expected, i tried to escape additional %'s but didn't work

Comment: You probably didn't place the command within a *batch* file.  If you're issuing from the command line, use `%` instead of `%%` in the command.

Comment: i saved it in a bat file, i tried with in a Windows7 64-bit machine (in case related)

Answer (score 1):

It is best to rename convert.exe to something like imgConvert.exe so it does not conflict with the Windows convert utility. Otherwise you should run it from the directory where the executable exists or specify the path or use an environment variable to get to it.

The vcomp100.dll is required for convert.exe to execute.

DOS does not like single quotes ('). Use double quotes (") where quotes are needed.